# Rails 2.3 with Oracle, How to optimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I am using rails 2.3 with Oracle database. Application is already running but database is having 2GB+ records now. I am told to perform optimization in the database.because now page is loading quite slow.and we found queries are taking much time.
and daily atleast 1000+ records are inserted into database

Would anybuddy let us know where should I start from?

Comment: Do it query by query.. 2GB is absolutely nothing for an Oracle database, we have indexes more than 15 times that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find the real bottlenecks. Which queries are the slow ones?
- If you found the slow queries, check the indices and add new ones where necessary.
- If you do a lot of single queries check, if you can combine them in joins and return larger chunks of data in one query.